# Products added via Magento REST API are out of stock even after specifying quantity

Tags: magento, magento2

I'm adding a product to my Magento store via the following curl but the dashboard shows that the item is `out of stock`.

```
curl --location '<store_url>/rest/V1/products' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer <secret_key>' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
    "product": {
        "sku": "380000",
        "name": "Men Plus Size Groube Striped Shirt",
        "attribute_set_id": 4,
        "price": "899.00",
        "weight": 0,
        "type_id": "simple",
        "status":1,
        "visibility":4,
        "custom_attributes": [
            {
                "attribute_code": "description",
                "value": "Shirt in super combed cotton."
            },
            {
                "attribute_code": "image",
                "value": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0591/5223/6751/products/Groube.Main.jpg?v=1676974530"
            },
            {
                "attribute_code": "url_key",
                "value": "men-plus-tshrt"
            },
            {
                "attribute_code": "brand_name",
                "value": "anup"
            },
            {
                "attribute_code": "tag",
                "value": ""
            }
        ],
        "extension_attributes": {
            "stock_item": {
                "is_in_stock": true,
                "qty": 4
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

I want to specify product quantity while creating the product via API.

Comment: The same issue with me, I even specify `manage_stock: true` but what I have for Salabale Quantity column is `No Manage Stock`! I work on Magento 2.4.5